# Three.JS how can load bin GLB(GLTF) from string variable with GLTFLoader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

ThreeJS how I can load bin GLB(GLTF) from string variable with GLTFLoader 
without modifications in loader script ?

GLTFLoader ( https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader ) 
RAW information bin-GLB already stored in var str before load? but loader wait URL of bin file then load and parse it itself :

```
str="glTF 9 0 JSON{"accessors":[{"bufferView":0,"componentType":5121,"count":456,
    "max":[85],
    "min":[0],"type":"SCALAR"},{"bufferView":1,"componentType":5126,"count":86,
    "max":[0.28029435873031616,0.2851730287075043,-0.5903046131134033],
    "min":[-0.2780577540397644,-0.27945515513420105,-1.1599042415618896],"type":"VEC3"},{"bufferView":2,"componentType":5126,"count":86,
    "max":[0.9879146814346313,0.9945066571235657,0.999969482421875],
    "min":[-0.9674672484397888,-0.9902645945549011,-0.999176025390625]"
```

UPDATE:  I know about  .parse method of loader but I have a function around current .load  function an additional promisfication and for have compatibilities with normal file loads can't change this function ((   because try to load this binary string as URi  Here is my testing  codepen with normal .load function   [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/den_tss/pen/aMvJmM?editors=1011)

Comment: Have you tried the loader's `parse( string, path, onLoad )` function? See https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader.parse.

Comment: Don, thnx !  I know about  .parse method of loader but I have around current .load  function an additional promisfication and for incompatibilities with normal file loads can't change this function ((   because try to load this binary string as URi  Here is my testing  codepen with normal .load function   https://codepen.io/den_tss/pen/aMvJmM?editors=1011

Comment: You’re going to have to use parse() for this - that’s its purpose. load takes a URL and not a JSON string.